# how to detect value changed in python, pandas in each object

Tags: python, pandas

> 180762508,1268510763,374723980,293,20180402035748,198,25,1,1
>   180762508,1268503685,374717256,307,20180402035758,225,38,1,1
>   180762508,1268492506,374708540,236,20180402035808,222,52,1,1
>   180762508,1268485868,374697563,248,20180402035818,197,47,1,1
>   180762508,1268482430,374688520,272,20180402035828,196,31,1,1
>   180707764,1270608366,374988433,246,20180402035925,66,37,1,0
>   180707764,1270620899,374992366,222,20180402035935,68,49,1,0

first column is unique id and the last column is my interest
I wanna know how can I find last column is changed from 0 to 1
I made a really big data frame with this dataset in pandas

```
import glob

import pandas as pd

path = r"1\1"

allFiles = glob.glob(path+"\*.DAT")

list=[]

for filename in allFiles:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header = None)

    list.append(df)

a = pd.concat(list)

a.head()
```

this is all I did

I don't have error but I wanna know the algorithm that I can find the last columns' value changed in each unique id
my goal is made a data frame that 
first column is unique id and second, third column is latitude, longitude which is in third, second columns in my dataset and the time stamp which is in 5th columns that last column's value is changed from 0 to 1

Comment: please show an example of your input and output dataframe (copy and paste)

Comment: The solution you're attempting to get, is if two values in the 'id' column match, test to see if the values in the last column are different? Would selecting only unique rows and then seeing if you have two non-unique values in the id column give your desired solution?

Comment: Your last two columns (binary ones) do not change within the same object. It conflicts with the question title.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you, you need to get the 5th row, where the change from 0 to 1, in the last column, takes place.

I made a dataframe with your first and last column (by the way, you said the 1st column is some kind of unique id, but I see repeated numbers), anyway based on your sample data, one possible solution is:

```
  import pandas as pd

  data = [[180762508,1],[180762508,1],[180762508,1],[180762508,1],[180762508,1],[180707764,0],[180707764,0]]

  df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['my_id','interest'])

  #new dataframe to compare the column interest
  df2 = df.loc[df['interest'] != df['interest'].shift(-1)] 
  #output:
  #        my_id  interest
  # 4  180762508         1
  # 6  180707764         0

   imax = df2.index.max() #index after the change
   imin = df2.index.min() #index before the change

   for i in range(imin,imax,1):
               i 

   #the row with the change in the original dataframe
   print(df.loc[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for posting. It looks like the first column doesn't have unique values, so I'm guessing you want to index returned or timestamp returned?

In any case, here's a sample of what might work for you if you want to find when the interest column for an ID changes from 0 to 1:

```
import pandas as pd

# Provided data
raw_str = """
180762508,1268510763,374723980,293,20180402035748,198,25,1,1 180762508,1268503685,374717256,307,20180402035758,225,38,1,1 180762508,1268492506,374708540,236,20180402035808,222,52,1,1 180762508,1268485868,374697563,248,20180402035818,197,47,1,1 180762508,1268482430,374688520,272,20180402035828,196,31,1,1 180707764,1270608366,374988433,246,20180402035925,66,37,1,0 180707764,1270620899,374992366,222,20180402035935,68,49,1,0
"""

# Replace newline and split on single whitespace
chunks = raw_str.replace('\n', '').split(' ')

# Create simple dictionary for ID, timestamp, and interest columns
ddict = {}
ddict['id'] = [i.split(',')[0] for i in chunks]
ddict['timestamp'] = [i.split(',')[4] for i in chunks]
ddict['interest'] = [i.split(',')[-1] for i in chunks]

# Convert dictionary to pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(ddict)

# Create dictionary for sample data
# This is an existing ID with timestamp in the future and 1 as interest
tdict = {
        'id': '180707764',
        'timestamp': '20180402035945',
        'interest': '1',
        }
```

What df looks like:

```
          id       timestamp interest
0  180707764  20180402035925        0
1  180707764  20180402035935        0
2  180707764  20180402035945        1
3  180762508  20180402035748        1
4  180762508  20180402035758        1
5  180762508  20180402035808        1
6  180762508  20180402035818        1
7  180762508  20180402035828        1
```

Continuing on:

```
# Append that dictionary to your dataframe and sort by id, timestamp
df = df.append(pd.Series(tdict), ignore_index=True).copy(deep=True)
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'timestamp']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Shift dataframe back 1 period by rows
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.shift(periods=-1, axis=0)

# Merge that dataframe with our original dataframe by index values
# We're dropping an extra id column and renaming our primary id column for aesthetics
df3 = df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_prev', '_curr'))
df3 = df3.drop('id_curr', axis=1).rename(columns={'id_prev': 'id'})
```

What df3 looks like:

```
          id  timestamp_prev interest_prev  timestamp_curr interest_curr
0  180707764  20180402035925             0  20180402035935             0
1  180707764  20180402035935             0  20180402035945             1
2  180707764  20180402035945             1  20180402035748             1
3  180762508  20180402035748             1  20180402035758             1
4  180762508  20180402035758             1  20180402035808             1
5  180762508  20180402035808             1  20180402035818             1
6  180762508  20180402035818             1  20180402035828             1
7  180762508  20180402035828             1             NaN           NaN
```

Now we can just create a conditional to return the row where interest changed from 0 to 1:

```
In[0]: df3[(df3['interest_prev'] == '0') & (df3['interest_curr'] == '1')]
```

Which returns:

```
   timestamp_prev interest_prev    id_curr  timestamp_curr interest_curr
1  20180402035935             0  180707764  20180402035945             1
```

You can also return specific columns by adding those onto the end of the result set:

```
df3[(df3['interest_prev'] == '0') & (df3['interest_curr'] == '1')]['timestamp_y']
df3[(df3['interest_prev'] == '0') & (df3['interest_curr'] == '1')][['id', 'timestamp_y']]
```

Or use the original dataframe (df) and `.iloc` to get specified data:

```
df.iloc[df3[(df3['interest_prev'] == '0') & (df3['interest_curr'] == '1')].index, :]
```

Out:

```
          id       timestamp interest
1  180707764  20180402035935        0
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying! It was really helpful